# how pthreads_cond_wait() works

Tags: c, pthreads, multiprocessing

I'm using `pthread_cond_wait()` and I'm still not sure how It works. I have more thread, which do this work:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
while(count() == 0){
        pthread_cond_wait(&signal, &mutex);
    }
//some critical section
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
```

Then I have a `main thread` where I call function `pthread_signal(&signal)`

How much threads are `waked up` after `signal` ? It's correct segment of code ?

Comment: One will "wake", and only if it was actually waiting.  If no threads were waiting on the cond-var when that signal was done, it becomes irrelevant. And yes, that code is correct, save for missing error checking, and assuming `count()` doesn't latch the mutex itself.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm using pthread_cond_wait() and I'm still not sure how It works.

That seems unwise.

> Then I have a main thread where I call function
>   `pthread_signal(&signal)`
>
> How much threads are waked up after signal ?

`pthread_cond_signal()` wakes at least one thread currently waiting on the condition variable, provided that there is any such thread to wake.  If called when there is no thread available to wake then it has no observable effect.

If there are multiple threads available to wake then more than one can be awakened, but the usual expectation is that only one will be awakened.  Inasmuch as spurious wakeups are also possible, however, code that correctly accounts for the full range of `pthread_cond_wait()` and `pthread_cond_signal()` behavior will have the correct semantics no matter how many threads are awakened, and it's not really possible to distinguish on this side of the interface between which and how many threads are awakened by a signal, and which are awakened spuriously.

> It's correct segment of
>   code ?

The code excerpt you presented appears to exhibit the correct form for using a condition variable.  In particular, it is always necessary to check the predicate associated with the CV both before waiting and after waking but before proceeding.  Your code does that correctly, supposing that `count() == 0` is the correct predicate.

Whether your overall program makes correct use of the mutex and condition variable is a separate question, however, and you have not presented sufficient information to answer it.  It is sometimes the case that a thread such as yours would need to signal the condition variable before it leaves the critical section.  It might also be that you want the main thread to perform a `pthread_cond_broadcast()` instead of a `pthread_cond_signal()`.  There are many other possibilities.

Comment: `pthread_cond_signal()` doesn't wake exactly one thread - it wakes *at least* one thread that's waiting on the condition variable, if there are any.  A conforming implementation could alias `pthread_cond_signal` to `pthread_cond_broadcast` if it wanted to.

Comment: Thank you, @caf, I have corrected my answer in that regard.